# Python: Iterate through Files in Multiple Dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a number of files in a dictionary that I want to run a script on.
Ordinarily, I would us 'os.listdir()' to list the files in my current working directory, and then tell my script to run on those files.

For instance:

```
dir = os.listdir():
for i in dir:
  do stuff
```

However, I want to run the script on these files when i am not in the current working directory. This will be so I can iterate through multiple folders later on.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `os.listdir()` takes a path parameter.  You can tell it to list files in any directory, regardless of your current working directory.  See documentation here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: The issue seems to be that when I list the files, I cannot load them in the same way.

For instance:
dir = os.listdir('path to dictionary')
for data in dir:
    something = load_file and do things

The above wont work, as it reads the file as a string in a list (i think)

Comment: @Wychh It's unclear what your issue is. `os.listdir()` will give you a list of filenames in a specified path, then you can just `open()` each of these files and do something with them. Perhaps you can show an example of what your trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`listdir()` takes a `path` parameter. You could use something like this:

```
filelist1 = os.listdir("/home/user/directory1")
filelist2 = os.listdir("/home/user/directory2")
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to read all files that are available under a directory:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
```

To list all available subdirs in a directory:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isdir, join

subdirs = [name for name in listdir(parent_dir) if isdir(join(parent_dir, name))]
```

Now let's combine those puzzles to list files only from sub-dirs of parent directory:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, isdir

parent_dir = "/foo/bar"
dirs = [name for name in listdir(parent_dir) if isdir(join(parent_dir, name))]
onlyfiles = []

for dir in dirs:
    f = [f for f in listdir(dir) if isfile(join(dir, f))]
    onlyfiles += f

print(onlyfiles)
```

Example output:

```
$ python dummy.py 
['Dockerfile', 'docker-compose.yml', '53009790.py', 'MOCK_DATA.csv', '53021557.py', '53023079.py']
$ python3 dummy.py 
['Dockerfile', 'docker-compose.yml', '53009790.py', 'MOCK_DATA.csv', '53021557.py', '53023079.py']
```

You can also try use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module, as it does pattern matching.

```
>>> import glob
>>> print(glob.glob('/home/rszamszur/*.sh'))
['/home/rszamszur/work-monitors.sh', '/home/rszamszur/default-monitor.sh', '/home/rszamszur/home-monitors.sh']
```

Key difference between OS module and glob is that OS will work for all systems, where glob only for Unix like.